# SlimPHP v3 how to display flash message on view

Tags: php, twig, slim, flash-message, twig-extension

In their new documentation there isn't anything for flash messages.

I installed the flash extension from their github repository (slimphp/Slim-Flash). Everything works fine, I can add messages and can also get these messages.

```
// Adding a message
$this->flash->addMessage('test', 'This is a message');

// Getting a message
$this->flash->getMessage('test')[0];
```

But this only works inside routes.  Of course I want to have these messages displayed on my view.

But I just don't know how to get this message on the twig view.

I have already tried:

```
{{ container.flash.message('test')[0] }}
{{ container.flash.getMessage('test')[0] }}
{{ this.flash.message('test')[0] }}
{{ this.flash.getMessage('test')[0] }}
{{ flash.message('test')[0] }}
{{ flash.getMessage('test')[0] }}
{{ app.flash.message('test')[0] }}
{{ app.flash.getMessage('test')[0] }}
{{ container.flash.test }}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the flash message inside the data attribute from the render method:

```
$this->view->render($res, 'path/to/template.twig', [
    'flash' => $this->flash
]);
```

Or you could add a middleware and add your flash instance to the twig parameters

```
$app->add(function ($request, $response, $next) {
    $this->view->offsetSet("flash", $this->flash);
    return $next($request, $response);
});
```

then it should be possible to access the messages inside the twig template with

`{{ flash.getMessage('test') }}`

Comment: Your solution with the middleware worked fine thank you. But instead of using $app->... you need to use $this->... After changing this, it worked fine.

Comment: Any idea how to do this for Slim 4?